# How do I create a method in UserManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I create a method in UserManager like:

```
public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
  UserManager.MyVoid();
  return View();
}
```

MyVoid it void will The desired her work

Comment: you want to return nothing from action ??

Comment: I understand it's hard to write English when it's not your native language, but honestly I have no idea about what you're trying to do here. What is MyVoid in the first place?

Comment: i want make MyVoid in UserManager class like Find() and Create()

Comment: "How to add method (`MyVoid`) to a class (`UserManager<T>`)" is not a good fit for SO - reading basic C# manual would be better place to find an answer.

Comment: I will search about "How to add method" to find my answer,thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return an empty result, you can use the [`EmptyResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.emptyresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    UserManager.MyVoid();
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: No,you not understand me and i want make MyVoid in UserManager class like Find() and Create() !

Comment: @YehiaElhawary: I still don't understand what you mean at all, I'm afraid. What do you mean by "like Find() and Create()"? In what sense? What *exactly* are you having problems with?

Comment: I want to create a void name it is Delete() in UserManager to use it to delete user

Comment: @YehiaElhawary: Okay, so do that. You haven't explained what the problem is.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Pretty sure the question is - how do I create a method, named MyVoid, with return type void, on the UserManager class.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil: Possibly. That seems to have very little to do with MVC though...